# How to add binary decimals/1s complement

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

From an answer sheet ....

$$0110.10_2 – 0011.01_2 = 0110.10_2 + 1100.10_{1s} = 0011.01_{1s}$$

My working from my understanding ...

```
 1  1  
 0110.10
 1100.10 +
----------
10011.00
```

How did the `.01` appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%27s_complement) you have an end-around carry when adding in 1's complement.  That high order bit in your sum becomes the low order 1